# CakePHP 3.2 slow loading of css files

Tags: css, cakephp-3.2

In CakePHP 3.2 I am having some problems with a slow loading of internal css files after clicking F5 (refreshing the page). The page is often overarranging elements according to the internal css file in an ugly visible to a user way.

The problem appears only on (quite small) css files which I load at the begining of my View pages. The main (big) css file - which is loaded at Layout/default.ctp - is never a problem - it is always quickly and fully loaded.

The main css file and the internal css files contain completely different elements. I do not override the same id's (e.g. #my_id{...}) in both of them. Therefore, I do not understand why the internal styles are loading slow.

I add css to the sub-pages with the following line (in the begining of every View file):

```
echo $this->Html->css('my-css-file');
```

I would rather user wait a little longer but to give him or her a full page with the correctly loaded css. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

can you post your internal css code? sometime internall css use @import to import/use external css, and that how your web become slowing down.

Comment: No @import is added. Css is just fine (very standard)